# How can i make the character to start/stop walking/running slowly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I mean that when the character is walking or running and getting to the clicked point he change the state in the animator from walk/run to idle so it looks like he walk then stop there is no animation between the walk/run and the start/stop.

I have 3 states in the animator. HumanoidWalk, HumanoidRun, HumanoidIdle.
I need something like fading.
For example if in the line:

```
_animator.CrossFade("Walk", 0);
```

I will change the 0 to 1 so when he start "Walk" it will be a bit slowly to walking speed. But in "Idle" if i will change it to 1 it will be something else not fading until he stop.

In other words i want to add fading effects when character start/stop walking/running and also when i click/double click and he switch between Walk and Run. Make some fade effects so it will not switch between the states so fast.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickToMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed = 5; // Determines how quickly object moves towards position
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private Animator _animator;
    private Vector3 destination;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    public float clickDelta = 0.35f;  // Max between two click to be considered a double click

    private bool click = false;
    private float clickTime;

    void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _animator.CrossFade("Idle", 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            if (click && Time.time <= (clickTime + clickDelta))
            {
                _animator.CrossFade("Run", 0);
                click = false;
            }
            else
            {
                click = true;
                clickTime = Time.time;
            }

            _animator.CrossFade("Walk", 0);
            Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            float hitdist = 0.0f;

            if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist))
            {
                Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
                targetPosition = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
                targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
                destination = targetPosition;
            }
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed);

        if ((transform.position - destination).magnitude < 0.7f)
        {
            _animator.CrossFade("Idle", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you using the Animator Controller? Isn't this kind of state blending what it was designed for?

Answer (score 0):

If you increase your transform duration value a little (like 0.25), then you can get a smooth transition between states. Also uncheck "fixed duration".